# What is the difference between the fleet missions?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-4

The mission a fleet is on affects its spread, but does it affect anything else? It looks to me that to raid convoys, Patrol (160% spread) is better than Convoy Raiding (120%) since presumably, I don't need a lot of forces to destroy a convoy.

Answer (score 1):

Depends, with `Patrol`, they will engage every type of enemy fleet. From battleships to destroyers and submarines.

`Convoy Raiding` will target only convoys and ships protecting the convoy.

If **your fleet** is **weaker** than the enemy, **avoid** `Patrol`.

Comment: It worth noting, that you can set the engagement risk level. When set to safe your navy will attack only weaker fleets.